# How can I output saved timezone shorthand (GMT, UTC, EST etc) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timezone, laravel-blade

So, basically I have a client that wants the timezone of his event to be displayed based on the timezone selected for the event e.g

Date: April 20, 2020

Location: Canada, Ontario

Time: 7:00pm

**Time Zone:** US/Eastern

**Displayed as:** 7:00pm (GMT) - > this should be equivalent to a shorthand of whatever Time Zone is chosen e.g (EST) and so on - and **not** the UTC equivalent (UTC-06:00)

I made him select timezones using https://github.com/camroncade/timezone

which uses the string representation of a time zone (US/Eastern)

I have these fields in my database to receive the inputs from my client on creation:

```
    $table->date('eventdate');
    $table->time('eventdaystarttime');
    $table->time('eventdayendtime');
    $table->string('eventtimezone');
```

My question is how to get the Shorthand of the Time Zone (eventtimezone) my client selected on creating the event (US/Eastern) and display it as this 7:00 pm (GMT) when outputting it in my blade.view file

Comment: Why is this "Urgent"?

Comment: I am working on the project now, and my deadline is for Tuesday! This is the only part left for me to complete the project.

Comment: I'm new to Laravel, but could [this info](https://www.qcode.in/managing-users-timezone-in-laravel-app/) possibly help?

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks for the reference - it helped me find what I needed using momentjs [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get timezone abbreviations / shorthand with php like this

```
$date = new DateTime('April 20, 2020');
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('US/Eastern'));
echo $date->format('T');
```

if you save supported timezone as listed on link below you can get them with carbon easily because US/Eastern doesn't work with carbon.

```
$tz = CarbonTimeZone::create('America/New_York');
echo $tz->getAbbr();
```

American timezone

https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Rest of World you can find here

https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: I keep getting CarbonTimeZone not found, even after importing carbon and trying to chain it to the method.

Comment: I have test with laravel 6 its working fine what version you are using?

Comment: It is currently running on Laravel 5.7.28

Comment: Thanks for your help tho, I've been able to use MomentJS to get what I need!